# Ansible: Extract string from multiple lines fact?

Tags: ansible

The following tasks:

```
- name: Set fact
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets/releases/download/v0.24.5/sealed-secrets_0.24.5_checksums.txt
    return_content: true
  register: checksums

- name: Output checksums
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: checksums.content
```

Return this format:

```
TASK [Output checksums] *********
ok: [localhost] =>
  checksums.content: |-
    0a5d37bfb646f31dc2d7270ba57aca1bd129bf975baf24dbce5576893e199948  kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-arm.tar.gz
    1ecaffe84c0c7c9db7fcd9c3a004f916e218c1cae48df26a87fa27842201ebec  kubeseal-0.24.5-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
    6bc27346b2f32c85e230161070ffe5c8502360b94aee4cfcedfc512de32543f8  kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-arm64.tar.gz
    90c28047caa071fc017c477b94e99d92f2ba2c8b800504f9ca9b87cbecffca77  kubeseal-0.24.5-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
    f3ba81d754f0c67e4bd13118d334cbdb816573e943395532dce674cdbe923710  kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-amd64.tar.gz
    f94d643194a5500ba19540e8b7a953f5c050387ddd0dd78a135de085a28c2fee  kubeseal-0.24.5-windows-amd64.tar.gz
```

My goal is to extract the checksum matching the `linux-arm64` regex and set it as fact:

```
TASK [Result] *********
ok: [localhost] =>
  result: 6bc27346b2f32c85e230161070ffe5c8502360b94aee4cfcedfc512de32543f8
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to extract the checksum matching the linux-arm64 regex and set it as fact:

This works:

```yaml
- name: set fact for checksum of linux-arm64
  set_fact:
    arm64_checksum: "{{ item.split(' ')[0] }}"
  loop: "{{ checksums.content.split('\n') }}"
  when: "'linux-arm64' in item"
```

We convert the output to a list by splitting it. Each newline is an item in the list, hence the `loop`.
Then, for each item on the list we only want the 'linux-arm64' line, hence the `when` clause.

Finally, we only want the first item on the line, providing us the desired result.

Note that there are multiple ways to rome.
It can also be solved by using the [select](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html) filter, and most likely other filters as well.

```yaml
- name: set fact for checksum of linux-arm64 by using select filter
  set_fact:
    arm64_checksum: "{{ checksums.content.split('\n') | select('match', '.*linux-arm64.*') | first | split(' ') | first }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select` filter as already suggested by Kevin. It's a bit simpler and safer than loops because you may have tasks with them included into other tasks, making nested loops, thus having to introduce `loop_control` and custom loop labels everywhere to distinct the loop variables.

```yaml
- name: Set fact for a regex
  vars:
    checksum:
      content: # ...
    regex_to_match: .*linux-arm64.*
  tasks:
    - name: Set fact
      set_fact:
        result: "{{
          checksum.content
            | split('\n')
            | select('match', regex_to_match)
            | first
            | split(' ')
            | first
          }}"
```

Note that I formatted the template to make it more readable but it's not a multiline one.

Comment: One can always choose to no use loop_control, and simply not include tasks in other tasks, preventing nested loops, right? It also reduces complexity i think.

Comment: Sure. But it usually works in the opposite direction so any modification requires some refactoring. I always use `loop_control` in the loops to make sure they will continue to work the same way if someone decides to reuse or redesign my code.

Answer (score 1):

Given the simplified data for testing

```yaml
    checksums:
      content: |
        0a5d37bfb646f31dc2  kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-arm.tar.gz
        1ecaffe84c0c7c9db7  kubeseal-0.24.5-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
        6bc27346b2f32c85e2  kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-arm64.tar.gz
        90c28047caa071fc01  kubeseal-0.24.5-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
        f3ba81d754f0c67e4b  kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-amd64.tar.gz
        f94d643194a5500ba1  kubeseal-0.24.5-windows-amd64.tar.gz
```

Create a dictionary

```yaml
  chck: "{{ dict(checksums.content.splitlines()|
                 map('split')|
                 map('reverse')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  chck:
    kubeseal-0.24.5-darwin-amd64.tar.gz: 90c28047caa071fc01
    kubeseal-0.24.5-darwin-arm64.tar.gz: 1ecaffe84c0c7c9db7
    kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-amd64.tar.gz: f3ba81d754f0c67e4b
    kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-arm.tar.gz: 0a5d37bfb646f31dc2
    kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-arm64.tar.gz: 6bc27346b2f32c85e2
    kubeseal-0.24.5-windows-amd64.tar.gz: f94d643194a5500ba1
```

Use it to search what you want. For example,

```yaml
  linux_arm64: "{{ chck|dict2items|
                        selectattr('key', 'search', 'linux-arm64')|
                        map(attribute='value') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  linux_arm64:
  - 6bc27346b2f32c85e2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    checksums:
      content: |
        0a5d37bfb646f31dc2  kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-arm.tar.gz
        1ecaffe84c0c7c9db7  kubeseal-0.24.5-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
        6bc27346b2f32c85e2  kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-arm64.tar.gz
        90c28047caa071fc01  kubeseal-0.24.5-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
        f3ba81d754f0c67e4b  kubeseal-0.24.5-linux-amd64.tar.gz
        f94d643194a5500ba1  kubeseal-0.24.5-windows-amd64.tar.gz

    chck: "{{ dict(checksums.content.splitlines()|
                   map('split')|
                   map('reverse')) }}"
    linux_arm64: "{{ chck|dict2items|
                          selectattr('key', 'search', 'linux-arm64')|
                          map(attribute='value') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: chck
    - debug:
        var: linux_arm64
```

Comment: I find the accepted solution by Kevin, a simpler implementation. Thoughts on the loop, Vladimir?

Comment: Sure. It's up to you. It depends on the use-case. There are many options: 1) More selections? Do you want a list, or just the first/last item? 2) Do you want to repeat the search with other strings? 3) Where do the strings come from? Is it easier to update the tasks or vars? 4) How do you want to test it? ...

Comment: @Floren, I find the here shown apporach with `dict(checksums.content.splitlines() | map('split') | map('reverse'))` more general and generic. It is also simpler to adopt for other Use Cases. I would choose this here as accepted solution. You may choose whatever fit for your needs.